# JS / RegEx to remove characters grouped within square braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I hope I can explain myself clearly here and that this is not too much of a specific issue.

I am working on some javascript that needs to take a string, find instances of chars between square brackets, store any returned results and then remove them from the original string.

My code so far is as follows:

```
parseLine : function(raw)
{
    var arr = [];

    var regex = /\[(.*?)]/g;
    var arr;
    while((arr = regex.exec(raw)) !== null)
    {
        console.log("  ", arr);
        arr.push(arr[1]);
        raw = raw.replace(/\[(.*?)]/, "");
        console.log("    ", raw);
    }

    return {results:arr, text:raw};
}
```

This seems to work in most cases. If I pass in the string `[id1]It [someChar]found [a#]an [id2]excellent [aa]match` then it returns all the chars from within the square brackets and the original string with the bracketed groups removed.

The problem arises when I use the string `[id1]It [someChar]found [a#]a [aa]match`.

It seems to fail when only a single letter (and space?) follows a bracketed group and starts missing groups as you can see in the log if you try it out. It also freaks out if i use groups back to back like `[a][b]` which I will need to do.

I'm guessing this is my RegEx - begged and borrowed from various posts here as I know nothing about it really - but I've had no luck fixing it and could use some help if anyone has any to offer. A fix would be great but more than that an explanation of what is actually going on behind the scenes would be awesome.

Thanks in advance all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the `lastIndex` property of the regex `/\[(.*?)]/g;` not resetting, since the regex is declared as global. When the regex has global flag `g` on, `lastIndex` property of `RegExp` is used to mark the position to start the next attempt to search for a match, and it is expected that the same string is fed to the `RegExp.exec()` function (explicitly, or [implicitly via `RegExp.test()` for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)) until no more match can be found. Either that, or you reset the `lastIndex` to 0 before feeding in a new input.

Since your code is reassigning the variable `raw` on every loop, you are using the wrong `lastIndex` to attempt the next match.

The problem will be solved when you remove `g` flag from your regex. Or you could use [the solution proposed by Tibos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21683412/1400768) where you supply a function to `String.replace()` function to do replacement and extract the capturing group at the same time.

Comment: That seems to have done the job :) One little 'g', who woulda thunk it. I should really sit down and read up on RegEx instead of just stealing bits from stackoverflow all the time. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You could use the replace method with a function to simplify the code and run the regexp only once:

```
function parseLine(raw) {
  var results = [];
  var parsed = raw.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, function(match,capture) {
    results.push(capture);
    return '';
  });
  return { results : results, text : parsed };
}
```

Comment: Still not working as I want but I like this approach, much tidier. Cheers.

Comment: @popClingwrap: Why is it not working as you want? I think this is much cleaner and to the point.

Comment: The approach is cleaner and maybe I didn't explain well - the code I posted is a simplification of what I'm actually using - but it only works as I want if I remove the 'g' from the regex. Which is why I marked the answer as I did. Kind of a joint effort I suppose and I really appreciate both answers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the last bracket: `\[(.*?)\]`.